# How to include a html string dynamically

Tags: php, html

I want to include a dynamic name for my picture

```
<img src='uploads/'"<?php echo $pic; ?>">
```

In the above code `$pic = myCatImage.jpg`

But it does not work

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your quotes are off:

```
<img src='uploads/<?php echo $pic; ?>'>
```

This value goes inside the same quotes as the rest of the value of the src attribute.